# DLL invoked from Powershell uses paths relative to Powershell install directory. How can I set it to something else?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, dll, log4net

I have a DLL with a static method which I am invoking from a Powershell script.

This static method performs some tasks and logs the results, using a log4net configuration which is shared with a website - the log4net configuration is based in a web.config file, and the Powershell script uses this web.config file like so:

```
[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", $webconfigpath)
```

This works great and log4net successfully picks up the configuration, which looks like so:

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="App_Data/log/process.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    [..]
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

The problem is that when it tries to use the relative path **App_Data/log/process.log**, it uses the base path of **C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\**.

How can I set this base path to a path of my choosing?

I don't want to use an absolute path in the web.config, as this code needs to work on several different environments with varying file system setups.

I have tried using the `Set-Location` cmdlet but this does not work. I have also tried setting `[Environment]::CurrentDirectory` but this also does not seem to work. No matter what I change, the DLL code will use the Powershell installation directory as its working directory.

My Powershell script looks like this:

```
$webroot = "$PSScriptRoot\..\webdir";
$webconfig = "$webroot\web.config";

# Neither of these seem to set the working directory for the DLL
#Set-Location $webroot
#[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $webroot

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Configuration")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$webroot\bin\Custom.Code.dll")

if (!(Test-Path $webconfig)) {
    Throw "Aborting, could not locate web.config at $webconfig";
}

[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE", $webconfig)

$result = [Custom.Code.Task]::Execute()

Write-Host $result
```

How can I provide a path for the DLL code to use as a relative base?

Comment: Hi @r41n, I can load my DLL and call code within it fine, thats not the issue. The issue is that log4net's configuration uses a relative path for the log file, but it is basing this relative path in the Powershell installation directory and not the running script's location.

Comment: I'm sorry, got it totally wrong it seems. Removed my useless comments.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly I'd say this is expected behavior. The DLL's code is executed in the directory that the calling processing is executed from. Using cd (aka. Set-Location) doesn't change the directory powershell.exe is started from, only the dir powershell is operating in. You could try to run Powershell and start another Powershell instance using the following example line `Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -WorkingDirectory c:\temp` and replace the "C:\temp" with the required directory, in that instance the script would probably be able to locate your config file.

Comment: The only other option I can think of on the fly is changing the DLL and make it accept a parameter which contains the directory of the config file.

Comment: Actually the Start-Process cmdlet syntax stated above throws an error. The following should do the trick: `Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -WorkingDirectory C:\` (It requires elevated privileges). I still think the best bet would be to adapt the code of the DLL to accept a parameter.

Comment: @r41n, thank you for this. I will give this a go this evening.

Answer (score 0):

The way we used to solve this for different *environments* was by using *environment variables*. Each dev has their own idea on where they want to log stuff, the prod environment has another set of location.

In your specific case, you could have in your PowerShell the following environment var :

```sh
$env:MyLogs = "$webroot\"
# or  [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("MyLogs","$webroot\")
```

And have your logger set up as such ([based on the log4net documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#fileappender)):

```
<file value="${MyLogs}App_Data/log/process.log" />
```

If you have more than just log4net that needs the variable, they should have their own ways of getting environment vars.